# How to solve a recurrence relation where $a_n$ has multiple restrictions?

Tags: recurrence-relations

How does one solve a recurrence relation like

\begin{equation}
  a_n=\begin{cases}
    Pa_{n-1} + C , & a_{n-1}=7k, k \in \mathbb{N}, k\text{ is even}.\\
    Qa_{n-1} + R , & a_{n-1} =7k, k \in \mathbb{N}, k \text{ is odd}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I know how to solve homogenous recurrence relations and non-homogenous recurrence relations of order 2. But not when there are multiple cases in them like this. Any help?

Comment: If anyone can point me to a method of finding a general solution for these little monsters, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Collatz problem? That's similar to what you're asking about, and is an infamous unsolved problem.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Are you sure this thing is unsolved yet? I was fooling around with something and ended up with this. Well if it's unsolved, I guess I'll just leave it be and move on to other things :'(

Comment: I mean that Collatz is unsolved. I don't know how hard your question is, I'm just pointing out that it's outwardly similar to Collatz, so it *might* be a very difficult problem.